# Remove double quotes around integers only in a csv file, regex?

Tags: regex, csv, sed, awk, gnu

I have a csv file with fields like so:

```
"231444","344","some string","222"
```

I have been trying, without success, to remove the double quotes from around the integers in the csv. I have tried a bit of sed, and attempted to awk/gawk but I am really having trouble with this one. Expected output would be:

```
231444,344,"some string",222
```

There are no negative integers. Any help would be much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can `some string` contain escaped `"` chars?

Comment: yes, it can contain escaped     " chars

Comment: then you need to test whatever answer you get with input like `"foo","\"some stuff\"1","2","bar" in it. I doubt if any of the answers posted so far will behave as you'd like.

Comment: @Ed Morton - I posted an answer with such regex.

Comment: @sln I tried your solution (with and without the `\G`, whatever that does) and got `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`. I'm sorry but a sed solution for this is completely unreadable and so unable to be maintained or enhanced or even debugged (by me at least!) so it should not be considered a viable solution.

Comment: @user2747676 - within your quoted string, how are double quotes escaped - by prefixing with a backslash (`\"`) or with a second double quote (`""`) or something else?

Comment: @Ed Morton - Hey Ed. Sorry you had bad luck trying out the regex. Maybe you just pasted wrong or quoted wrong. The `\G` anchor can be removed, just need to wrap `s/(?: existing regex, no \G) | (.)/\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8/sg`. There is nothing unusual in the regex except a single lookahead assertion `(?=)`. That can be changed too. You can't complain about escaped quotes and produce a simple regex. Every single character has to be parsed. If you have a simpler solution, post it.. If sed uses BRE, then some metachar quoting is in effect.

Comment: No, I didn't past wrong, nor did I quote wrong. There will be no simple and robust solution. Once the OP tells us his requirements and data format then we can start considering whether or not to invest our time helping him solve the problem.

Comment: @Ed Morton - It works great in Perl, I just posted a test case. Its robust and very simple. Maybe you could adapt it to bash. Good luck!

Comment: "very simple" - not by a long way. Anyway, let's see what the OP tells us about how his `"`s are escaped (whether by preceeding them with `\ ` or by a second `"`) and go from there. I suspect the answer will be to simply point him to Lorance Stinson's awk CSV parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for a reference. This things are can be done using Perl's one liner as well.

linux:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/"(\d+)"/$1/g' input.txt
```

For reference, Windows(single quote doesn't work):

```
perl -i.bak -p -e "s/\"(\d+)\"/$1/g" input.txt
```

Comment: This is... beautiful. Wow. Thank you. Looks like it's time to learn perl. Thank you for taking time from your day to answer.

Comment: @ Paul Vargas lmao. I'll keep that in mind. Although, looking at the source for a few perl scripts I use, I see that it is at least more readable than shell script.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex would be `/"(\d+)"/g` which should be replaced with `\1`.

Without knowing sed, I assume it'd be something like this (based on the [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#Substitution_command)):

```
sed 's/"(\d+)"/\1/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

[Regex 101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wP5bZ7)

Comment: doh. I was using something very similar, but without the +... so it was only matching one digit. :/

Comment: Also, regex 101 demo link is great. Thank you!

Comment: The GNU sed syntax will be `sed 's/"\([[:digit:]]\+\)"/\1/g'` or `sed -r 's/"([[:digit:]]+)"/\1/g'` -- sed does not have perl's RE syntax (\d)

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the info - didn't know that. Time to learn sed!